# Flutter: capture the future of the 2nd page after PushReplacement

Tags: flutter, future

I have some code like:

```
Future pushNamed = Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => XYZPage(),
        ));
pushNamed.then((_) => setState(() {}));
```

In general, this works fine, except for a case: in the XYZPage(), when the user clicks a button, it does a pushReplacement to another page ABCPage(). When that happens, the code above already gets to pushNamed.then. What I want instead, is to intercept the future when page ABCPage() finishes and refresh the current page before XYZPage(). Is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Flutter [push documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/push.html) says:

'Returns a Future that completes to the result value passed to pop when the pushed route is popped off the navigator.'

The Future **is not** the builder Future. Its' Future that finishes on `page.pop()`.

So if you want to listen to the `pop()` of the page - this is possible, just as you did

If you want to respond to `builder: (context) => XYZPage(),` you should do it inside `XYZPage.build()`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way by using RouteAware and DidPopNext().